# Add 1440 minutes from current timestamp in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am using `[unixtime]` in TCL which uses this code:

```
proc unixtime {} { return [clock seconds] }
```

How can I add 1440 minutes (1 day) from the returned time?

Comment: You mean you want 1 day from the time the command `unixtime` was called? (i.e. if the command was called on 1st January 2015 at 1:00pm, then the command would return the unixtime of the 2nd January 2015 at 1:00pm?)

Comment: @Jerry Yes I want to call it and then add 1 day on to it. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `clock add ... 1 days`:

```
% proc unixtime {} { return [clock seconds] }
% set time [unixtime]
1429558336
% clock format $time
Mon Apr 20 14:32:16 CDT 2015
% set time [clock add $time 1 days]
1429644736
% clock format $time
Tue Apr 21 14:32:16 CDT 2015
```

Note: this adds 1 day to the time. This is not always 1440 minutes (24 hours). It could be more or less if there are changes related to daylight savings (23 or 25 hours).

But if you actually do want to add 1440 minutes use `clock add ... 1440 minutes`:

```
% set time [clock add $time 1440 minutes]
1429731136
% clock format $time
Wed Apr 22 14:32:16 CDT 2015
```

To illustrate the difference, here in the US we went to summer time on March 8th this year:

```
% set time [clock scan "Mar 7 08:00:00 2015"]
1425736800
% clock format $time
Sat Mar 07 08:00:00 CST 2015
% clock format [clock add $time 1 days]
Sun Mar 08 08:00:00 CDT 2015
% clock format [clock add $time 1440 minutes]
Sun Mar 08 09:00:00 CDT 2015
```

Comment: That's the _canonical_ answer for Tcl. ___DO IT THIS WAY!___